# Kotlin почему цикл выполняется всего один раз?

Tags: android, kotlin, циклы

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
    fun test(view: View) {
        var num = 0
        for (i in 0..4)
            num++
        val testSay = Toast.makeText(this, num.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        testSay.show()
    }
}
```

Почему цикл for не выполняется при каждом срабатывании onClick()? Получается всегда один и тот же тост, который равен 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал Ваш код в реальности. Несколько выводов:

1. Цикл выполняется каждый раз при вызове функции  `fun test(view: View)`.
2. Ваш опубликованный в вопросе код показывает "5" а не
   "6", вероятно Вы не точно перенесли условия в вопрос.
3. Показывается `toast` только 1 раз потому что он стоит после цикла. И выполняется после того как цикл закончился и проинкрементировал `num` до 5.

Если хотите что бы тост показывал при каждом витке цыкла, то есть 5 раз, то нужно его поместить в сколуп цикла. Пример ниже:

```
fun test(view: View) {
    var num = 0
    for (i in 0..4){
        num++
        val testSay = Toast.makeText(this, num.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        testSay.show()
    }
}
```

Отсутствие фигурных скобок возлагает на Вас ответственность помнить о том, что если Вы не оборачиваете тело метода в фигурные скобки, то метод (в данном случае `for (i in 0..4)`) выполнит только следующу за ним строчку. А вот `Toast` в данном случае уже будет вне его ответственности, потому то он выполняется только один раз в порядке очереди при вызове родительского метода `fun test(view: View)`.

Answer (score 2):

не совсем понятно почему 6.
При вызове метода цикл отрабатывает и `num` должен быть равен 5.
Если вы хотите чтобы `num` сохранял свое предыдущее значение и увеличивался каждый раз при вызове метода, то можно сделать так через **Shared Preferences**:

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
var num = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", 0); 

val testSay = Toast.makeText(this, num.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
testSay.show()

SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit(); 
myEdit.putInt("counter", num+1);
```

Comment: Я начинаю изучать язык и хотел бы уточнить - разве при каждом нажатии на Button содержимое функции, которая это нажатие обрабатывает, не выполняется полностью?

Comment: выполняется. при нажатии у вас запускается цикл, который ПРОСТО увеличивает значение num до 5 и останавливается. дальше идет вывод toast

Comment: О, точно. Я же никуда не сохраняю значение... Спасибо, вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так оберните цикл в скобки фигурные=) у вас в теле цикла только num++

У вас же даже отступ намекает, что то что ниже num++ за пределами for

Comment: Не решило проблему. 
    fun rema(view: View) {
        var num = 0
        for (i in 0..4) {
            num++
        }
        val remaSay = Toast.makeText(this, num.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        remaSay.show()
    }

Comment: Возвращает всё так же одно и то же число при каждом нажатии на кнопку